# What is the difference between update-grub and update-grub2?

Tags: grub2

I'm making some changes on my grub file under `/etc/default/grub`. In some tutorials I have seen `sudo update-grub` and others `sudo update-grub2`. What is the difference?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There is no difference.

Ubuntu 9.10 and later have GRUB2 installed, but `sudo update-grub` has still prevailed as the standard command.

**`sudo update-grub` and `sudo update-grub2` are equivalent, so it doesn't matter which one you run.** `/usr/sbin/update-grub2` is just a [symbolic link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to `/usr/sbin/update-grub`.

```
ek@Del:~$ ls -l `which update-grub update-grub2`
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 64 May 17 03:07 /usr/sbin/update-grub
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 May 17 03:22 /usr/sbin/update-grub2 -> update-grub
```

- Actually, *generally speaking* sometimes one command can be a symbolic link of another, and yet they behave differently, because the executable checks *how* it was invoked (i.e., by what name) and behaves accordingly.

  That is **not the case** for `update-grub2` and `update-grub` though, which are both provided by packages like `grub-pc` that provide GRUB2. Furthermore, `/usr/sbin/update-grub` is actually just a short shell script that does most of its work through yet another command, and we can look at its complete 3-line source code (in Ubuntu 12.04) to see that the name used to invoke it is not checked:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  set -e
  exec grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg "$@"
  ```

  `"$@"` expands to all the command-line arguments passed after the name `update-grub` or `update-grub2`, but not that name itself. And this is the only place in the script that command-line syntax is checked at all.

Comment: Excellent, thorough, educational answer. Would upvote more than once if I could!